# Error with selenium firefox webdriver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, junit

I am getting the following error when I try to run a test case in Selenium. I have Firefox 19.0 installed on my system and I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port
>   7054 within 45000 ms System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
>   'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45' Driver info:
>   driver.version: FirefoxDriver     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:92)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:71)

I have tried various versions of Firefox but the error persists. Is this a compatibility issue? If yes, any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Is there another process hanging on to port 7054?

Comment: I did not see any process hanging on that port

Answer (score 0):

Try closing all applications that could potentially use ports and retry. Or try disabling your firewall/antivirus.

Also updating webdriver or firefox may help.